# Javascript countdown function returns NaN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, countdowntimer

Here is my function which is called once at the beginning of my vue.js program.

```
countdownTimer() {
        this.countdown = 60;
            var downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
            if(this.countdown <= 0){
                clearInterval(downloadTimer);
                if (this.thisUser.captain) {
                        Store.submitTurnEnd();
                    }
            }
            this.countdown = this.countdown - 1
            console.log(this.countdown)
            }, 1000);
        },
```

It is displayed as so
`<div id="countdown-timer" v-if="this.gameState.turnInProgress" :style="{visibility: this.countdown >= 0 ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">{{countdown}}</div>`

However, the value does not update in my html file and returns NaN in console.log. Thanks for the help.

Comment: change ```setInterval(function(){})``` by ```setInterval(() => {})```. This changes your ```this``` scope.

Comment: Thank you! Yes that worked, however now my timer is being weird and counting down fast after I click a few times.

Comment: I am not a vue fella. But what I think that you have to update the ```countdown``` value of ```data``` object. So that reactively render.